# A subset of the space of all real sequences is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded and one other condition.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $s$ be the space of all real sequences $x=(x_n)$ endowed with the metric
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|)}.$$
Prove that a subset $X\subset s$ is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded and there exists a sequence $M_n$ such that $|x_n|<M_n$ for any $x\in X$ and $n\geq 1$.

For the forwards direction I have closed and bounded, but I'm stuck with the third condition. Additionally, for the backwards direction, I have that this is equivalent to showing $X$ is totally bounded since it is complete. Any help/hints appreciated!